# smarty - Fatal Error: Call to a member function createTemplate() on a non-object

Tags: php, smarty

I've got some problems when configuring smarty, version 3.1.12.

When I try to extract some data from database, it runs "Fatal error:  Call to a member function createTemplate() on a non-object in F:...\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 47"

But if the program does NOT extract from database, it runs ok. For example:

```
<?php
include "smarty/smarty.class.php";
$smarty->assign('title', 'I'm title');
$smarty->assign('content', 'I'm content');
$smarty->display('test.html');
?>
```

Below is the codes I'm using.

inc.php

```
<?php
// Load smarty class file.
require("sys.smarty.php");

$smarty = new Smarti();
?>
```

sys.smarty.php

```
<?php

// Load smarty class file.
require("smarty/smarty.class.php");

class Smarti extends Smarty{
    function Smarti() {
        $this->setTemplateDir("../smarty/templates");
        $this->setConfigDir("../smarty/configs");
        $this->setCompileDir("../smarty/templates_c");
        $this->setCacheDir("../smarty/cache");      
    }
}
?>
```

I don't know where went wrong. I can extract data from database in some other way, so it's not the database problem. Could u guys lend me a hand? Thx~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Smarty constructor` sets a member variable to itself. Do it from the `constructor` of your extended `Smarti` class.

```
class Smarti extends Smarty{
  function Smarti() {
    $this->smarty = $this;
    ...
```

But it would be better to call the Smarty constructor itself.

```
class Smarti extends Smarty{
  function Smarti() {
    parent::__construct();
    ...
```

Comment: thx! U really helped me a lot. I cannot tell'ya how exciting I'm now!